# Coldfusion 11 address validation

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I have been looking around the web and I can not find anything on how to do an address validation.  Just to make sure that the person is entering a valid address/city/zip.

Comment: I'm not sure this is an appropriate Stack overflow/coldfusion question. There are databases for zip codes (as well as web services) and Google Maps API/WS will probably suffice for validating an address. Neither of these is specific to ColdFusion.

Comment: You need to give some indication of having actually tried *something*, or having done some research or... *anything* to solve your own problem. I do not believe there is *nothing* on all of Google offering an address validation API.

Answer (score 0):

+1 what Mark mentioned above. I have used Melissa Data in the past for address validations. I would call their web service, and pass the full address which a user entered.

Then, Melissa Data would provide simply wrong, correct or provide alternative addresses in case of misspelling or missing information.